# sonar-scanner-vsts task fails to install in TFS 2017

Tags: sonarqube

I'm getting an error when installing the sonar-scanner-vsts downloaded from the marketplace and installed in TFS 2017 with the version 4.0:
*The task.json file was not found in contribution tasks/scanner-cli.*

Looking over the source at git-hub, looks like folders were added but the manifest JSON was not updated with the new paths. Is this a new issue?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Im having the same problem

Comment: I cloned the code from git-hub and added in the full paths within the resources section of the vss-extension manifest. I did a private build and then successfully installed the extension in TFS 2017. I have done a pull request yet, I'm hoping that someone from SonarSource will reach out.

Comment: Jesse, @WillEllis could you confirm which update of TFS 2017 you are using please? The new v4 version of the extension packages multiple versions of the tasks, using a feature that was added in [TFS 2017 Update 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2#multiple-versions-of-extension-tasks).
I've successfully installed and run the extension on TFS2017.2.

Comment: @duncanp same issue here. I'm running TFS 2017 RTM (v 15.105.25910.0)

Comment: Thanks @Marthijn We've confirmed that it's an issue with installing v4.0 of the extension on TFS2017 Update 1 or earlier (because those older versions of TFS only support extensions that contain a single version of a task).
There is a manual workaround listed in the [VSTS-135](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VSTS-135) ticket i.e. use the _tfx-cli_ command line tool to install the previous version of the extension.

Comment: [Update] it's possible to upload the previous version of the extension using the TFS UI so I've updated the workaround listed in the ticket to describe that method instead (using the _tfx-cli_ command line didn't work for me).

Comment: I uploaded the previous version successfully. Once we have upgraded TFS we'll use the newest extension. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked on [VSTS-135](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VSTS-135) and the fix should be released within a week.